# Ajax response not loading in view page

Tags: mysql, ajax, codeigniter

Iam Working in full calendar functionality.But there is no data showing in the view page.Only showing the calendar itself.Can anyone please help me to find a solution.Here is my code:

VIEW PAGE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).on("click", ".calendarview", function () {  

        var roomid = $(this).data('id');
        //alert(roomid);exit;

         $('#calendar_view').fullCalendar({
            //events: [
    //          {
    //                  title: 'All Day Event',
    //                  start: roomid
    //              }
    //                  ]
            events: {
            url: base_url+'home/calview',
                dataType: 'json',
               data: {roomid: roomid},
               type: 'POST', // Send post data
               error: function() {
                 alert('There was an error while fetching events.');
               }
            }
         });
    });
</script>
```

IN CONTROLLER

```
function calview()
       {
                    $room_id =$this->input->post('roomid');
                    $events=$this->Home_model->find_room_availability($room_id); 
                        $data_events = array();
                        foreach($events as $r) {
                    $data_events[] = array(
            //"title" => $r->available,
                    "description" => 'available',
                    "start" => $r->dt);
                        }
                echo json_encode(array("events" => $data_events));
                exit();
        }
```

MODEL:

```
function find_room_availability($room_id){
    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT x.dt , r.room_cnt - COALESCE(SUM(`booking_cnt`),0) available FROM calendar_table x LEFT JOIN bookinglist y ON x.dt >= y.`date_from` AND x.dt < y.`date_to` LEFT JOIN rooms r ON r.id=$room_id WHERE x.dt BETWEEN now() - interval 3 month AND now() + interval 5 month GROUP BY dt ");                                           
    //echo $this->db->last_query();
    //exit;
  return $result->result();     

}
```

Ajax response is like

```
[[{"title":"10","start":"2017-04-26"},
  {"title":"10","start":"2017-04-27"},
  {"title":"10","start":"2017-04-28"},
  {"title":"10","start":"2017-04-29"},
  {"title":"10","start":"2017-04-30"},
  {"title":"10","start":"2017-05-01"},
  {"title":"10","start":"2017-05-02"},
  {"title":"10","start":"2017-05-03"},
  {"title":"10","start":"2017-05-04"},
  {"title":"10","start":"2017-05-05"},
  {"title":"10","start":"2017-05-06"},
  {"title":"10","start":"2017-05-07"},
  {"title":"10","start":"2017-05-08"},
  {"title":"10","start":"2017-05-09"},
  {"title":"10","start":"2017-05-10"},
  {"title":"10","start":"2017-05-11"},
  {"title":"10","start":"2017-05-12"},
  {"title":"10","start":"2017-05-13"},
  {"title":"10","start":"2017-05-14"},
  {"title":"10","start":"2017-05-15"},
  {"title":"10","start":"2017-05-16"},
  {"title":"10","start":"2017-05-17"},}]]
```

can anyone please help me to find a solution

Comment: May be remove exit();

Comment: that was also tried but didn't get the solution

Comment: The problem in ajax response it starts from  `[[{` and end with `},}]]` but you want response like this `[{"title":"10","start":"2017-04-26"},{"title":"10","start":"2017-04-27"},{"title":"10","start":"2017-04-28"},{"title":"10","start":"2017-04-29"},{"title":"10","start":"2017-04-30"},{"title":"10","start":"2017-05-01"},{"title":"10","start":"2017-05-02"},{"title":"10","start":"2017-05-03"},{"title":"10","start":"2017-05-04"},{"title":"10","start":"2017-05-05"},{"title":"10","start":"2017-05-06"},{"title":"10","start":"2017-05-07"}]`

Comment: No sir, My response is like,
[[{"title":"10","start":"2017-04-26"},{"title":"10","start":"2017-04-27"},{"title":"-12","start":"2017-11-02"},{"title":"-12","start":"2017-11-03"},{"title":"-21","start":"2017-12-24"},{"title":"-23","start":"2017-12-25"}]]

Comment: but where is `events` object in Ajax response which get from server -> `json_encode(array("events" => $data_events));`

Comment: Can you please explain more

Comment: i got the crct answer when i give static data like
events: [
    {
     title: 'All Day Event',
     start: '07-07-2017'
   },
 {
     title: 'All Day Event',
     start: '07-07-2017'
     },
    ]
Can you please tell how to pass data from controller

Comment: @Aswathi check here which type object you want and compare it to your response object https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/

Answer (score 0):

On Clicking on Calendar name class you get the data in the form of json in AJAX SUCCESS CALL, Now you need to assign that data with the help java script .html() format

Because you are not sending data to view page directly, you are sending in ajax format as a success response

```
success: function (data) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(data);
  $('#testdiv').val(obj.test);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

set page header in controller

```
function calview(){
    $room_id =$this->input->post('roomid');
    $events=$this->Home_model->find_room_availability($room_id); 
    $data_events = array();
    foreach($events as $r) {
        $data_events[] = array(
            "title" => $r->available,
            "description" => 'available',
            "start" => $r->dt
        );
    }
    //set output header as json
    $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output(json_encode(array('events' => $data_events)));
}
```

change your js script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", ".calendarview", function () {
    var roomid = $(this).data('id');
    $('#calendar_view').fullCalendar({
    events: function(start, end, timezone, cb) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '<?=base_url("home/calview");?>',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {roomid: roomid},
      success: function(response) {
          var events = response.events;
          //pass object to callback function
          cb(events);
      }
    });
  }
 });
});
</script>
```